# Metadata Property not showing in search results

Tags: search, metadata

I created a column named "Issue Category" in a issue tracker list. And then, I created a new metadata property with the same name . After that I done two full crawls, but I could't see search results for "IssueCategory:EE" .

metadata property:
[image]

crawl property:
[image]

search result:

[image]

newest:

When I saw the crawl log , I find a record that 'The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when attempting to download the item.' on the site. But is not from my list url. The error page is searchadministration.aspx .

Comment: Do you have any scopes that could be interfering?

Comment: @JamesLove All setting is default. I don't have to create any scopes. Need to create a new scope?

Comment: Shouldn't need to - default scopes include *everything* by default.

Comment: @JamesLove But the custom metadata property didn't work in this way.The original metadata property had a perfect work.

Comment: Do you find the item when you use free text?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Yes. I'm sure all items had been crawled. Just use 'metadata property : value' receive nothing.

Comment: Could it be a language issue? I am not well versed on multi-lingual and search.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I also think that could be a language issue,but when I use the same language on native metadata property like 'title:test', items could be received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work, you need to set up a search schema in the site collection.

On the Managed Properties page, in the Managed property field, type the name of the site column that you want to find the managed property name of.

[image]

When that is done, do the full crawl again and see if you get results from that property.

Reference: [How to display values from custom managed properties in search results - option 1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/09/11/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-results-option-1.aspx#FindMPName)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can find all of my custom metadata properies in this page. And every time I do the full crawl follow any change . Some different from yours that is my sharepoint versions of 2010.I do not know this will not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure below:

1. Managed properties are properly mapped to required crawled properties
2. Do a full crawl
3. Ensure that the display template (if edited by adding the new managed property) is uploaded and published
4. Ensure that the "Update" link in the notification bar is clicked in Result types screen (better to check both at spweb and spsite levels)
5. Clear browser cache

Perform a search now and see if the new MP is coming up.
If still they are not showing up, use the Search [SearchQueryToolv2.6](https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) to query and find if the Search API is throwing them up. If all seems fine then do below

Final nail in the coffin would be **restarting the SP Timer and SP Administration services**. (This step made my changes reflect. Though for others, it worked at step 5)